# remove html tag contains a word sed

Tags: html, sed, tags

In config file i have several this

```
 <tagwidth> <!-- Short -->
    <x>213</x>
    <y>590</y>
    
</tagwidth>
```

and all tags are same name  but only what is changed is text after (Short, Long, Medium, etc).

```
    <tagwidth> <!-- Short -->
        <x>213</x>
        <y>590</y>
        
    </tagwidth>
<tagwidth> <!-- Medium -->
        <x>413</x>
        <y>890</y>
        
    </tagwidth>
<tagwidth> <!-- Long -->
        <x>1213</x>
        <y>1590</y>
        
    </tagwidth>
```

How to remove whole  which contains name Short after it.
So i want to remove  with Short, whole that x and y lines, basically whole tag.
So result must be

```
 </tagwidth>
<tagwidth> <!-- Medium -->
        <x>413</x>
        <y>890</y>
        
    </tagwidth>
<tagwidth> <!-- Long -->
        <x>1213</x>
        <y>1590</y>
        
    </tagwidth>
```

i tried with this but didnt help

```
cat config.xml | sed 's/<tagwidth><!-- Short --></tagwidth>//g'
```

Comment: Maybe `sed '/<tagwidth> <!-- Short -->/,/<\/tagwidth>/d' file`?

Comment: it just print it out, but when i > it to another file, its blank. Why?

Comment: Did you use `sed -i '/<tagwidth> <!-- Short -->/,/<\/tagwidth>/d' file`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sh
sed -i '/<tagwidth> <!-- Short -->/,/<\/tagwidth>/d' file
```

*Details*:

- `-i` - GNU sed option to perform changes inline
- `/<tagwidth> <!-- Short -->/,/<\/tagwidth>/` - find a block of lines where the first line contains `<tagwidth> <!-- Short -->` and the second line contains `</tagwidth>`
- `d` - delete the found match(es).